# Function composition and commutation exercise

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

I am learning from a self-paced math course and has this exercise on function composition that I couldn't wrap my head around, can you please help me solve it.
I proved that $f^2 \circ f = f \circ f^2$ but I don't know how to answer the why part or the second part of the question so any help to solve it and understand the logic behind it is appreciated.

Suppose $f:R \rightarrow R$ is a function from the set of real numbers to the same set with $f(x)=x+1$. We write $f^{2}$ to represent $f \circ f$ and $f^{n+1}=f^n \circ f$.
Is it true that $f^2 \circ f = f \circ f^2$? Why? 
Is the set ${g:R \rightarrow R l g \circ f=f \circ g}$ infinite? Why?

Comment: If you show $f^n \circ f = f \circ f^n$ and each $f^n$ is distinct, then this is an infinite subset.

Comment: @Dayton $f^n$ is distinct it is the result of $f^n \circ f$

Comment: You need $f^{n} \neq f^{m}$ for $m\neq n$, then you are done.

Comment: @Dayton can you please provide a step by step answer

Comment: $\{f^n | n\in\mathbb{N}\} \subset \{ g | g\circ f = f\circ g \}$ and $\{f^n | n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite since $f^n\neq f^m$ for $n\neq m$.